# String manipulation from text for Ubuntu/Linux bash script

Tags: linux, string, bash, ubuntu

how can I capture only few words from a text using bash script Ubuntu/Linux
as below

> Input test
> : authentication invalid AND Username2
>
> Output text will be: authentication invalid Username2

> Input test
> : ERROR AND username1
>
> Output text will be: ERROR username1

> Input test
> : Permission denied for UserID AND Username5 AND IP:222.222.222.0
>
> Output text will be: Permission denied for UserID Username5 IP:222.222.222.0

I want to eliminate AND word from the text.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `var=$(sed 's/AND[ ]//' input)`? or `var=input; var="${var/AND /}";`? (depends on how you get the input) For example `a="authentication invalid AND Username2"; echo "${a/AND /}"`

Comment: `sed 's/\bAND\b//g' file.txt `

Comment: `awk 'gsub(/[ ]AND[ ]/," ")' file.txt` is another option. If you already have it in a variable, then for a global replacement, it would be, e.g. `var="${var// AND / }";`

Comment: Thanks you guys..I will check and update accordingly.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin absolutely brilliant!! thanks a lot..it's working

Comment: @Jetchisel awesome help! it's working too..thanks..

Comment: Good, glad it helped -- good luck with your scripting!

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin do you know? If I have another query regarding similar string issue, do I need to ask here or I have to open new question?? Assist me, I am new here.

Comment: If it is a short one, just drop a comment here. If it is a full question -- better to author another question. You can refer back to this link in your new question if there is much commonality. But if it is just another variable manipulation -- a comment will probably do. (I may have to answer in a few hours -- bedtime (past) here)